# what is the best method to "resize a pool to increase node count" in azure batch account?

Tags: azure, azure-batch-account

what is the best method to resize a pool to increase number of nodes in azure batch account that's running in production ?

Answer (score 0):

The Azure portal for sure, it will ask you what to do about running and queued tasks. You can also issue Azure CLI commands, see [az batch pool resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/batch/pool?view=azure-cli-latest#az-batch-pool-resize).

The absolute best way IMHO is to have an auto-scale formula, e.g.:

```
$NodeDeallocationOption = taskcompletion;

minNodes = 1;
maxNodes = 10;

activeTasks = $ActiveTasks.GetSample(1);
runningTasks = $RunningTasks.GetSample(1);

totalTasks = activeTasks + runningTasks;


nodes = min(max(minNodes, totalTasks), maxNodes);
$TargetDedicated = nodes;
```

Update min and max nodes, evaluate the formula (optional) and save it and the pool will rescale.